# Run python script for one month non-stop

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I have a code for scraping streaming tweets using Tweepy library for Python.
I'd like to scrape streaming tweets for one month without stopping on Mac. 
Could you please advise me how to do it from a technical point of view?

Comment: you can have worker that run the scraping function every hour/day/month using celery(https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/getting-started/introduction.html)

Comment: What do you mean by "for one month"? When would you want it to finish if started on a day number of the month that does not exist in the next calendar month?

Comment: @alaniwi the dates don't really matter, sorry if I didn't make myself clear. The idea is to run the code continuously without interruptions to be able to scrape as many tweets as possible and not to have gaps. When this month starts and ends doesn't really matter. It can be one month and 10 days, I just wrote one month as an example of a long period.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the time module

```
import time
print(time.strftime("%b", time.localtime(time.time())))
>>> Jun
```

You can conditionally check the month like so:

```
print(time.strftime("%b", time.localtime(time.time())) == "Jun")
>>> true
```

Just execute your program in a while loop

```
while time.strftime("%b", time.localtime(time.time())) == "Jun":
     # your code here
```